# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

Tags: android

Please help me out. When ever i am trying to build gradle or try to Run the app getting the error as below :-

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

Here is my build.gradle(app):-

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ABC.DEF.GHI"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/adjust-android-4.11.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-6.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile project(':lib_slidingpanel')
    compile project(':lib_dotted_loading')
    compile project(':lib_viewpagerindicator')
    compile project(':lib_annotation_validator')

}
```

And here is my menifiest.xml code:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ABC.DEF.GHI"
     >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- flurry analytics -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.model.Globals"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/winepairing_app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" >


        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.ForgetPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_forget_password" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.MenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.BaseActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.FoodWithWineActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_food_with_wine"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.WineWithFoodActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_wine_with_food"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.ListAllWineActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_all_wine"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.TipsAndVideosActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tips_and_videos" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.AboutWineClubActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about_wine_club"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.BuyInBulkActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_buy_in_bulk"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.BuyOnlineActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_buy_online"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.ShareAppActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_share_app"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHIMyProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_profile"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.ResetCodeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reset_code" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.ResetPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reset_password" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.ContactUsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_us"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.ChangePasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_change_password" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.DishDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_change_password"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.WineListWithCategoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_wine_list_with_category"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.FairPriceActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fair_price"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.WineDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fair_price"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.ListAllWineDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_all_wine_details"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.WineOfMonthActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_all_wine_details"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.PreviousWineNotesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_all_wine_details"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.VideosActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_all_wine_details"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.FilterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_all_wine_details"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.VideoPlayerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_video_player"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.OrderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_video_player"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.FilterResultsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_filter_results"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ABC.DEF.GHI.WineNotesDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_wine_notes_detail"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Where i replaced my package name with

> ABC.DEF.GHI

please help me out. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: done but problem still .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hapening because of tour drawable images please check them and than clean thw project.
Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Open application manifest(AndroidManifest.xml), click on Merged Manifest.

[Check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AASRy.jpg)

You can view error in right colum ,try to solve the error.It may help some one with same problem.